# Formstone upload - get upload context

Tags: file-upload, jquery-plugins

I would like to send some context information along with the file being uploaded, as I have multiple upload areas on the page and want to associate each upload with the area that was used for upload. The `beforeSend` option is available, but all I have in that function is the actual `file` object and a `formData` object which I will put additional data in.

How can I know which upload area was clicked? I'd like to send this info to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly an issue with the current implementation. The best way to solve this today would be to specify a different `beforeSend` callback for each upload instance:

```
$(".upload_one").upload({
    beforeSend: preprocessUploadOne
});

$(".upload_two").upload({
    beforeSend: preprocessUploadTwo
});

// etc..
```

Each preprocess function could then prepare the `formData` in a unique way (or collect the relevant data and pass it along to a single preparation function, as long as you return the `formData` object from each step).

Depending on how your scripts are structured, you could also reference those individual global callbacks with the inline data options, allowing you to continue using a single instantiation call:

```
<div class="upload" data-upload-options='{"beforeSend":preprocessUploadOne}'></div>

<div class="upload" data-upload-options='{"beforeSend":preprocessUploadTwo}'></div>
```

I'll also open an issue to address this problem in a more sustainable way in a future release.

Comment: Thank you! That would be a great addition to the plugin.
I will see if I can make this suggestion work, as the upload areas are being added dynamically to the page which complicates things.

Comment: I ended up putting some custom code in the plugin to identify the area that was clicked.

Comment: Version 1.2.1 was released yesterday. The `this` variable will now be scoped to the component in the `beforeSend` callback.